# How to set suhosin.post.max_vars in a htaccess file

Tags: htaccess

I need to add this values to my htaccess:

```
suhosin.request.max_vars = 8000
suhosin.post.max_vars = 8000
```

If I just add them like that I get an **Internal Server Error**

Which is the right way to include them?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that Apache doesn't know what to do with those values, hence the internal server error. You need to change the lines to the following:

```
php_value suhosin.post.max_vars 8000
php_value suhosin.request.max_vars 8000
```

The `php_value` causes the setting to be passed along to PHP. If you were setting boolean values (true/false), you would use `php_flag` instead. This will only work if you are running PHP as an Apache module. Otherwise you have to edit the php.ini file, which may not be an option.

For more info on using `php_value` and `php_flag`, see the relevant PHP documentation page:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

**Edit:**

According to `rhoyerboat`'s suggestion, the next issue you run into is that your PHP installation does not allow modification of the Suhosin Post variables on a per directory basis. You're going to have to get someone with access o the php.ini file to add `suhosin.perdir = "p"` to the file for the above .htaccess trick to work.

Comment: I added the lines as you said, now no error message is shown but phpinfo() show that the values hasn't change, suhosin.post.max_vars stil is 200 . Look this picture http://content.screencast.com/users/chefnelone/folders/Snagit/media/c7d32713-d2f9-42b3-9df7-82381ec0a74e/2012-05-17_15-54-39.png

Comment: @chefnelone See updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

Up-voting the last answer and also, the next problem is Suhosin's perdir directive.

perdir is visible in your phpinfo() output, but not in the Suhosin docs. This site explains pretty well, http://www.mattzuba.com/2011/04/suhosins-suhosin-perdir-directive/#more-153

Answer (score 1):

Not all server types allow using php_flag and php_value and for those server types you would need to add these directives in a php.ini file instead.